# How to declare a specific protocol in Structure in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a structure in Swift:

```
struct foo: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var someView: View
}
```

Here someView is any kind of SwiftUI View struct. But Xcode will raise error

> Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

How to declare a property that follow a specific protocol in Swift?

Comment: You can use `AnyView` instead of `View`

Comment: Why do you need a struct like this? What is your *goal*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use generics, if that works for you:

```
struct Foo<T: View>: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var someView: T
}
```